# how to count column(with data) number in laravel excel maatwebsite

Tags: laravel-4.2, laravel-excel

```
if(Input::hasFile('excel_file')){
    $path = Input::file('excel_file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
        $reader->setDateFormat('Y-m-d');                
    })->get();

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $highestColumn = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    echo $highestColumnIndex;
    exit();
}
```

I can import excel file and count the rows are there by using $data->count(). But i can't figure out column numbers. How can i get how many columns are in the rows?i tried with phpexcel too but failed.need the solution badly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = Input::file('excel_file')->getRealPath();
$data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
    $reader->setDateFormat('Y-m-d');

    $objExcel = $reader->getExcel();
    $sheet = $objExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); 
    Session::put('val',$highestColumnIndex);    

})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but can help for others:
Get columns like:

```
function getColumnNames($sheename, $path){
    return Excel::selectSheets($sheename)->load($path)->keys()->toArray();
}
```

Then count:

```
count(getColumnNames('my_sheet', $my_file);
```